# Unable to install Parse package via Cocoapods. Missing library

Tags: ios, parse-platform, xcode6, cocoapods

Senario: 
I'm studying parse.com inter-table relationship via code.

I've set up a cocoapod dependency and am working from the .workspace.

This is the podfile content:

```
platform :ios
pod 'Parse', '~> 1.7.2.1'
```

However I received the following compiler error:

[image]

Apparently I'm missing a Library. 
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try rerunning `pod update` from the project folder via the command line, then cleaning your build.

Also, you don't need to be quite to specific with your podfile. Try this instead:

```
platform :ios
pod 'Parse', '~> 1.7'
```

Comment: I did a cut/paste from 'pod search parse' for the version/Parse.  I generalized it to 1.7.   But doing a general cleansing of the build didn't change to problem.

Comment: Did you remember to run 'pod install' or 'pod update' from the command line?